# css not work without DOCTYPE !

Tags: css, doctype

Is there a way that without DOCTYPE tag all css are working ?

Comment: why the hell you want to do such a thing ?

Comment: "CSS" does work without a DOCTYPE. But CSS is a very broad topic. What is your exact problem?

Comment: I agree with @remi... why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a proper doctype, the page will be rendered in quirks mode. CSS will still work, but it will work differently.

What quirks mode mean exactly differs a lot from browser to browser. It has a very big impact on Internet Explorer, as it even uses a [different box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Browsers use the Doctype to determine if they should go into standards (aka strict) mode or quirks mode.

In quirks mode browsers are deliberately buggy so that they are compatible with bad CSS written for ancient, buggy browsers. The results are inconsistent.

It is essentially an intelligence test — is the author of the page smart enough to try to write to standards? If not, assume their CSS is just as bad.

The solution is to write good markup.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to use a doctype. You don't want your webpages to run in quirks mode, really.